# Respresting linear transformation with matrix with restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra

When given a set of restrictions, what is the way to find a representing matrix of a linear transformation?
Lets say I have T:R^4->R^3 and I need the Ker(T) to be spaned by {(1,2,3,4), (0,1,1,1)}.
What are the things I need to do? (In general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the given family on a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ and you can define $T$ on many ways but what it's important is to assign to the two given vectors the zero vector of $\Bbb R^3$ and to the two last vectors of the basis two vectors of $\Bbb R^3$ that are linearly independent.